# Golang MongoDB Driver NoSQL Injection

Tags: mongodb, go, sql-injection, nosql-injection

I am wondering if this mongoDB driver for golang is susceptible to an injection attack:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver

Not able to find it documented, or glean it from the internal workings of the package.

It uses bson.D and bson.M internal map types for filtering, so it should be fairly easy to scrub the params and secure, just wondering if anyone knows for sure:

https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.2.1/bson?tab=doc

For example, can we safely do something like this?

```
    filter := bson.D{{"token", token}}

    result := []struct {
        AccountID string `bson:"account_id"`
        Token     string `bson:"token"`
    }{}

    // coll is *mondo.Collection
    cur, err := d.coll.Find(ctx, filter)

    err = cur.All(ctx, &result);
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you have a concrete exploit or a founded suspicion that one might exist, it is best not to post it in public on StackOverflow; see [responsible disclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsible_disclosure). If you're just asking whether injection can happen when using this library: it all depends on how you're using it, so please show some code.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Edited with a code sample.